# Magento 1.9.3 Get OrderID from order view programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I need to add my own function on **Order View** page, but how can I get the **orderID** programmatically on the current order I'm viewing?

[image]

I have tried this code so far, which is triggered when Adding Order Comment

```
public function commentSaveAfter($observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();   
    $from_shipment = false;
    if (!empty($orderIds)) 
    {



    }
}
```

it gives me an error,

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in
```

Comment: what you have tried earlier?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code will help you this is my code in my block class

```
protected $order;

public function getOrder() {
    if (is_null($this->order)) {
        if (Mage::registry('current_order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('order');
        }
        else {
            $order = new Varien_Object();
        }
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    return $this->order;
}
```

Comment: This is working for me.  and works for the event sales_order_status_history_save_after

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Order Detail in `Sales -> Order`. Try below code to get Order Object.

```
$_order = $this->getOrder(); 
$order_id =  $_order->getId();
$incremtnt_id =  $_order->getIncrementId();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can I get the orderID after the event sales_order_status_history_save_after?

Comment: yeah try `$order = $observer->getOrder()->getId();`

Comment: Just tried, and I got this error. Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on null in

Comment: Try different event.. or check the example of your current event

Comment: You can try `sales_order_status_before` and `sales_order_status_after` event